# Save data to JSON File in correct format - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently saving click co-ordinates to a JSON file through the use of the following code:

```
onmouseup = function(e){
  var Clicks = {};
  Clicks.state = {
    cX: e.clientX,
    cY: e.clientY,
  }
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "PHP/save_json.php",
    data : {
      state : JSON.stringify(Clicks.state)
    }
  });
}

<?php
$myFile = "JSON/clicks.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["state"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

However with the above code I am saving the coordinates in the following incorrect format:

{"cX":467,"cY":374}{"cX":56,"cY":474}

Can anyone please help me to save the coordinates in a JSON array rather than in seperate JSON entries?

I would like the file to be as follows, were the coordinates are added onto the already existing JSON array within the file:

```
{ 
   "ID":["1","2"],
   "cX":["467","56"],
   "cY":["374","474"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need load data to array, add new data and save back to file.

I think you don't need save numbers in strings.
These code create new file if not exists.

```
<?php
// test input data
if(isset($_GET['state']['cX']) && 
   isset($_GET['state']['cY']) && 
   is_numeric($_GET['state']['cX']) && 
   is_numeric($_GET['state']['cY']) ) 
{
    // ok
} else {
   exit('Bad data format');
}

$myFile = __DIR__ . "/JSON/clicks.json";

// step 1, load data from file to array
$array = file_exists($myFile) ? 
    json_decode(file_get_contents($myFile), true) : 
    [];

// step 2, add data to array
$array['ID'][] = isset($array['ID']) ? (count($array['ID']) + 1) : 1;
$array['cX'][] = (int) $state['cX'];
$array['cY'][] = (int) $state['cY'];

// step 3, save array back to file
file_put_contents($myFile, json_encode($array));
```

Or you can use other file format where will be possible to append file. The easiest format for static structured data could be [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: I have implemented the provided code, however im receiving "Bad data format". Do I need to change anything with how Clicks.state is being created?

Comment: I think the problem is due to JSON.stringify(Clicks.state) which is passing cX and cY as strings

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

- Open the *clicks.json* file and read the entire contents.
- Turn this into an instance of `stdClass` by using `json_decode`.  This will give you a PHP object that you can modify using normal PHP functions and syntax.
- Use `json_decode` on the JSON that you receive from your client.
- Use `array_push` to push the new values from the client into the arrays stored in the file (something like `array_push($fileJson->cX, $clientJson->cX);`)
- Use `json_encode` to encode `$fileJson` again.
- Write it back to the file.

This assumes that the *clicks.json* file is already correctly formatted JSON with the arrays already created etc.

Answer (score 1):

Given the current arrangement of the `key` and `value` bits, it's apparent that some sort of transformation is needed in the JSON data before it is written to the file. Where this transformation is done is definitely a matter of an opinion. However, assuming that you receive following JSON data in PHP:

```
[{"cX":467,"cY":374},{"cX":56,"cY":474}]
```

The PHP code can be written as (illustrated with static input):

```
$myFile = "JSON/clicks.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["state"];
$json_array_source  =   json_decode($string, true);

$json_array_target  =   array();
foreach($json_array_source as $key=>$value){
    $json_array_target["ID"][]  =   $key + 1;
    foreach($value as $sub_key => $sub_value){
        $json_array_target[$sub_key][]  =   $sub_value;
    }
}

$transformed_string = json_encode($json_array_target);
fwrite($fh, $transformed_string);
fclose($fh);
```

If you were to `echo $transformed_string;`, you'd see:

```
{"ID":[1,2],"cX":[467,56],"cY":[374,474]}
```

Which is what will be written to the file.

Answer (score -1):

Use json_encode to convert your string to an object, then convert it back to a string using json_decode and the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option.

```
$stringData = json_decode(json_encode($_GET["state"]), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: This isn't going change the actual structure of the JSON.  Look at his given output and what he wants it to look like.  He has created the object wrong.